# Migrate MySQL to DB2

Tags: mysql, sql, db2, database-migration

I need to migrate some MySQL tables (or a schema) to DB2 database.

What tools we have to do this on a automatically way?

I prefer some free or open source tools, but with we have very interesting paid ones I would like to know too.

I need to migrate MySQL to DB2, but if we have tools that can do migrations on both sides (MySQL to DB2 and DB2 to MySQL) will be very interesting too.

Comment: Questions about recommending a tool are specifically off-topic:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: I dont need a tool recomendation, I need any tool that do this. I'm not look for the best one, or something based on opinion, I just asking for something that can convert mysql to db2 automatically.

Comment: ... that would still be a tool recommendation.  What, are you expecting us to say "Hey, here's this tool, but you shouldn't use it" (...which would also be a recommendation)?  Generally speaking, list questions are also off-topic, because there isn't a finite set of answers.  What does Google/Bing/other search engine turn up?  Look there, and try to use one.  At minimum, exporting the tables as CSV file and table creation scripts would work, although you'd need to make some changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an IBM Redbook called *MySQL to DB2 Conversion Guide* (http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247093.html) describing the process, it may have references to some tools.